# Getting empty promise from a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Can someone please suggest why i am getting an empty promise in this case ?
Promise { undefined }
I am seeing data with console.log right before the return, so its not throwing any errors.

```
const getObj = async (bucket, path) => {
  try {
    let timer = us.now();
    time_log('info', util.format('Getting object'));
    minioClient.getObject(bucket, path, function(err, stream) {
      if (err) { _throw({ code: 'internal_error', severity: 1, user_code: 'internal_error', reason: util.format('unhandled_exception occured in getObj function: %s', err)}) };
      let buffer = '';
      stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        buffer += chunk;
      })
      stream.on('end', function() {
        time_log('mile', util.format('getObj response_took: [%s]', us.parse((us.now() - timer)).toString()));
        return(JSON.parse(buffer));
      })
      stream.on('error', function(err) {
        throw(err);
      })
    })
  }
  catch (e) {
    throw({ code: 'internal_error', severity: 1, user_code: 'internal_error', reason: util.format('unhandled_exception occured in getObj function: %s', e)});
  }
}

console.log(getObj('configs', 'nodes.json'));
```

Comment: What does `getObj('configs', 'nodes.json').then(result => console.log(result))` print?

Comment: Its returning undefined

Answer (score 1):

`async` functions are supposed to return promise. In your cases you don't return anything. You could do something like this:

```js
const getObj = async (bucket, path) => {
try {
    let timer = us.now();
    time_log('info', util.format('Getting object'));
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      minioClient.getObject(bucket, path, function(err, stream) {
          if (err) { reject({ code: 'internal_error', severity: 1, user_code: 'internal_error', reason: util.format('unhandled_exception occured in getObj function: %s', err)}) };
          let buffer = '';
          stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
            buffer += chunk;
          })
          stream.on('end', function() {
            time_log('mile', util.format('getObj response_took: [%s]', us.parse((us.now() - timer)).toString()));
            resolve(JSON.parse(buffer));
          })
          stream.on('error', function(err) {
            reject(err);
          })
      })
    })
  }
  catch (e) {
    throw({ code: 'internal_error', severity: 1, user_code: 'internal_error', reason: util.format('unhandled_exception occured in getObj function: %s', e)});
  }
}

console.log(getObj('configs', 'nodes.json'));
```

Comment: I though this line was supposed to be turned into a resolve in async function,         return(JSON.parse(buffer));

Comment: Or do i need to wrap       minioClient.getObject(bucket, path, function(err, stream) { in another promise ? i was under assumption that it should be covered by the initial async function

Comment: `return(JSON.parse(buffer));` returns inside callback function, not from async function itself. Yes you need to wrap handling stream functionality in the Promise.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!